# Bind <div> to element of Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

We have a somewhat complicated model on an AngularJS controller:

```
function controller($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        childmodel1: {
            childmodel2: {
                property1: 'abc',
                property2: 3,
                property3: 0.5,
                property4: 'abc'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the HTML markup, we don't want to repeat the whole access chain everytime we access `childmodel2`:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.childmodel1.childmodel2.property1" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.childmodel1.childmodel2.property2" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.childmodel1.childmodel2.property3" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.childmodel1.childmodel2.property4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there an AngularJS directive that creates a sub-scope like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-unknowndirective="model.childmodel1.childmodel2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="property1" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="property2" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="property3" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="property4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

It's the same thing that's done on `ng-repeat`, but without the repetition :)

We tried `ng-scope`, `ng-controller`, `ng-model`, none of them works this way. Googling didn't yield any results, we don't know the terminology to search for.

Comment: Why don't you create another directive for that and pass `model.children.childmodel2` to it?

Comment: No experience here creating custom directives. I thought this would be such a common task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Ufuk, here's my solution:

```
mt.directive('subscope', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            subscope: '='
        }
    };
});
```

and

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div subscope="model.childmodel1.childmodel2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="subscope.property1" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="subscope.property2" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="subscope.property3" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="subscope.property4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As @Reza said you can use `ng-init`. Or you could simply do `$scope.childmodel2 = $scope.model.childmodel1.childmodel2`. Using an isolate scope could lead to some unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) to suppress the `access chain`

```
<div ng-init="childmodel2 = model.childmodel1.childmodel2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="childmodel2.property1" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="childmodel2.property2" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="childmodel2.property3" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="childmodel2.property4" />
</div>
```

It creates `alias model`. More appropriate you create the alias **in your controller** like

```
$scope.childmodel2 = $scope.model.childmodel1.childmodel2 // and remove ng-init from HTML
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/L8RkZHHXSYHa96HSr37T?p=preview)